# In Bash, how do you delete all files with same name, except the one located in a specific folder?

Tags: bash, find, rm

I have a specific file which is found in several directories. Usually I delete all of them by using the syntax:

```
find . -name "<Filename>" -delete
```

However, I want to retain one file from a specific folder, say FOLDER1.

How do I do this using find? (I want to use `find` because I use `-print` before `-delete` to check what files I am deleting. I am apprehensive on using `rm` since there is danger of deleting files I want to keep.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding using `find` rather than `rm` so you can use `-print` first: Your apprehension is reasonable, but note that with `rm` you can accomplish the same thing by prepending `echo`.

Comment: ...or, perhaps better than prepending `echo`: `shopt -s extglob`, followed by (on a separate line, since extglob is a parser option): `printf '%q ' rm !(FOLDER1)/filename; echo` -- that way, names with whitespace, hidden characters, etc. are printed unambiguously, and the output is a `rm` statement that can be copy/pasted back to the shell without worrying about what a directory name embedding the literal string `$(rm -rf .)` would do.

Comment: ...of course, the above extglob assumes that FOLDER1 is an immediate subdirectory of the current working directory, and that the files to delete are only one directory deep; adjust to suit (perhaps running `shopt -s globstar` and using `**/!(FOLDER1)/filename`, f'rinstance) otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with

```
find . -name "filename" -and -not -path "./path/to/filename" -delete
```

You will want either to make sure that the path expression is a relative one, including the initial `./`, so that it's matched by the expression, or else use wildcards. So if you know that it's in a folder named `myfolder`, but you don't know the full path to it, you can use

```
find . -name "filename" -and -not -path "*/myfolder/filename" -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to delete **anything** under any directory named FOLDER1, you can tell `find` not to recurse down any directory so named at all, using `-prune`:

```
find . -name FOLDER1 -prune -o -name filename -delete
```

This is more efficient than recursing down that directory and then filtering out results that include it later.

---

Side note: When testing this, be sure you use the explicit `-print`:

```
find . -name FOLDER1 -prune -o -name filename -print
```

...whereas an implicit one won't behave as you expect:

```
# not what you want: equivalent to the below, not the above:
find . -name FOLDER1 -prune -o -name filename
```

...will behave as:

```
find . '(' -name FOLDER1 -prune -o -name filename ')' -print
```

...which thus includes contents on *either side of* the `-o` operator for the action.